# How to prevent monkey to open status bar?

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I want to use android's monkey for stress test my app but monkey opens status bar and changes settings on my phone.

To start monkey I use:

```
 adb -s S5660a19e722f shell monkey -p com.lmmx.app -v -v -v 10000 --throttle 500
```

I thought that `-p com.lmmx.app` parameter must prevent this...
I use 2.3.5 and 2.3.6 phones for testing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

I have a 5.0(lollipop) phone and was able to do this with 
[screen pinning](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/16-things-you-can-do-in-android-lollipop-that-you-could-1659628014)

1. activate it with settings>security>screen pinning
2. press the app switcher/multitasking button next to your home button
3. on the bottom corner of each app in the recents apps list will be a pin icon

From there you can run monkey on your device without it changing.

Comment: Nice solution without if(monkey) checks!

Comment: This is the way to go! :)

Comment: This is a nice solution, but do you know how to unpin application on emulator? You have to hold press back and overview buttons *at the same time*...? edit: NVM, you have to [restart emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440692/1906123)

Answer (score 3):

I just created an app that will mask the status bar for the exact same purpose.

It just adds **a system overlay over the status bar**, preventing anyone from accessing the status bar.

You can check it out here : [github sources](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/simiasque)

It works great for our monkey tests, especially on launcher apps.

Feel free to use it. If you want to directly download an apk you can find it [here](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/simiasque/raw/master/demo/simiasque-debug.apk)

Comment: Your app not work on android Oreo and newer. Do you know some other solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can hide status bar in code use `isUserAMonkey ()`

```
if(ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()){
//your code
}
```

Setup Monkey to ignore or prevent status bar is impossible because you can't limit some area on screen or disable some function in Monkey keys.