# How to exit from Screen Pinning - Android 5 (Emulator)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

Screen Pinning ([as mentioned on this page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise)) is a new feature introduced in Android 5 (Lollipop) which lets its users to temporarily lock only one Activity to the screen. All other notifications are hidden when screen pinning is activated.

Following steps can be taken to activate Screen Pinning

> Users can enable screen pinning in Settings > Security > Screen Pinning, and select the tasks they want to pin by touching the green pin icon in the recents screen.

And to exit from Screen Pinning user can do the following

> the user can exit by holding both the Back and Recent buttons

What I wanted to ask is

> Is there any way to exit from Screen Pinning on Android Emulator for 5.0?, as we won't be able to press both Back and Recent buttons at same time with mouse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can unpin with an adb command: `adb shell am task lock stop`

Comment: interestingly this is throwing error "_Activity manager is not in lockTaskMode_" but working.

Comment: This is now the correct answer.  ps - agree the response message is misleading but the command does work.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot exit from the Screen Pinning Mode manually from the Emulator as we will not be able to press both Back button and Recents button at **same time**.

However if we `restart the emulator` the screen pinning is turned off automatically.

There is no other way around to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no 'hardware button' in your emulator to do just that, you could add a button in your app with the following functionality.

```
public void exitScreenPinning()
{
    try
    {
        stopLockTask();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Screen was unlocked already.");
    }
}
```

That is, if you are using the screen pinning in your own app.

Comment: I am not asking programmatically. To exit from Screen Pinning, the Back button and recents button both should be pressed at same time. How can you press both of them with mouse at same time?

Answer (score 0):

To exit from Screen Pinning, the Back button and recents button both should be pressed at same time. This is doable with certain combination. Press "Shift" button on middle of the button (center of back and recents button). Then press "Cmd" and move mouse - two "fingers" appear. Select back and recents buttons, press and hold for several seconds.